# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^210^{-n}$ converge to $\frac{110}{3^6}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^210^{-n} = \frac{110}{3^6}$$ 
I noticed this while playing around on my calculator. Is it true and how come?

Comment: Are you familiar with power series? Namely, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{n-1}=\dfrac{1}{1-r}$$if $|r|<1$ (in this case, $r=\frac{1}{10}$, and you can deal with the $n^2$ term by considering the derivatives of the power series).

Comment: @user170231 No not familiar with power series, but I'll look into it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 x^n = x \frac{d}{dx} \left [x \frac{d}{dx} \left (\frac1{1-x} \right ) \right ] $$

because

$$\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$

Evaluating the derivatives, we get

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 x^n = \frac{x(1+ x)}{(1-x)^3}$$

Plug in $x=1/10$ and the expected answer results.

Comment: Does this method have a name.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: not that I am aware of.  However, experience tells us that increasing powers of $n$ in the sum are results of taking derivatives of the function represented by the sum, so long as the resulting sum converges.

Answer (score 2):

This is because:
\begin{align*}
\sum_n n^2x^n&=x^2\sum_n n(n-1)x^{n-2}+x\sum_n nx^{n-1}\\
&=x^2\Bigl(\frac 1{1-x}\Bigr)''+x\Bigl(\frac 1{1-x}\Bigr)'\\
&=\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}+\frac x{(1-x)^2}=\frac{x^2+x}{(1-x)^3}=\color{red}{\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}}.
\end{align*}
Then set $x=\dfrac1{10}$.